# In-place set element removal in multiple sets during iteration

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, lambda, list-comprehension

I have two sets of objects, s1 and s2, whose lengths are different. I want to in-place modify these two sets based on this pseudo-code:

```
for a1 in s1:
  for a2 in s2:
    if a1.name == a2.name:
      # insert some stuff into database
      # remove a2 from s2 and a1 from s1
```

s1 and s2 now have only elements whereby s1[n].name != s2[n].name. Removing items from the sets should, of course, not affect the rest of the ongoing iteration.

I realize there is more than one way to solve this. I'm struggling to figure just one "python-style" way (i.e., not using nested for loops): map? filter? lambda? list comprehensions? Algorithm performance isn't particularly important because the sets are very small -- never more than 100 elements each but usually around 10 each.

Comment: Why would you want to modify the sets in-place considering their sizes?

Comment: I recommend using a 3rd set, as modifying collection you are iterating over is dangerous - you don't change your wheels whilst driving a car, do you?

Comment: Turns out it's way too complicated to do this with a new set() because I need to retain elements where a1.name != a2.name without duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

*Updated*

I rethought this. For in-place:

```
for a1 in s1:
    for a2 in s2:
        if a1.name == a2.name:
            s1.remove(a1)
            s2.remove(a1)
```

and for a more "python-style" way:

```
s1_filtered = [r for r in s1 if r not in s2]
s2_filtered = [r for r in s2 if r not in s1]
```

*Previous*

Just do--

```
for a1 in s1:
  for a2 in s2:
    if a1.name == a2.name:
        del a1 #you get an error
        del a2 #you get an error
        # insert some stuff into database
        # remove a2 from s2 and a1 from s1
```

Comment: After the first time a1 and a2 are deleted, I get this error: if a2.name == a1.name:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a1' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

Since I dont have 50 rep to comment code, I will write like a regular answer:

```
for a1 in s1:
  for a2 in s2:
    if a1.name == a2.name: # since a1 may have been deleted while iterating through s2 .name is essentailly called on null and thats where you get UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a1' referenced before assignment.
        del a1 #you get an error because a1 was previously deleted 
        del a2 #you get an error
```